# Swift Completion Handler never called when using DispatchGroup

Tags: swift, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the SwiftyBluetooth library to connect to bluetooth peripherals. I have the following code which tries to establish a connection with a peripheral:

```
init?(peripheral: Peripheral) {
    SwiftyPeripheral = peripheral

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var Success = false
    group.enter()


    peripheral.connect(withTimeout: nil) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            Success = true
            group.leave()
            return
        case .failure(let error):
            Success = false
            group.leave()
            return
        }
    }

    group.wait()

    if(!Success) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

If I remove the dispatch group the code works just fine; but with the dispatch group there; the completion handlers are never called. I have tried calling peripheral.connect on a background thread to no avail.

//=======Edit==========

Talked to the library Dev and apparently this library is meant to run on the mean thread so it would appear I'm deadlocking the main thread. Is there some other pattern I can use to wait? I don't care how I do it; I just need to wait for that connection before I return from the constructor

//=====Edit 2=====

Here's another scenario where this causes trouble:

Here I have a read-only property that is read from the peripheral. So; the first time the property is read it should be read from the peripheral and after that it can simply be read from memory.

```
    var PeripheralType : peripheralType {
    get {

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

        if(_peripheralType == peripheralType.unknown) {

            semaphore.wait()

            SwiftyPeripheral!.readValue(ofCharacWithUUID: CharacteristicUuid.DeviceProtocol.rawValue, fromServiceWithUUID: ServiceUuid.DeviceInformationService.rawValue) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let data):

                    switch(data) {
                    case Data(hex: "0x01"):
                        self._peripheralType = peripheralType.TypeOne
                        semaphore.signal()
                    case Data(hex: "0x02"):
                        self._peripheralType = peripheralType.TypeTwo
                        semaphore.signal()
                    default:
                        self._peripheralType = peripheralType.unknown
                        semaphore.signal()
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    self._peripheralType = peripheralType.unknown
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            }
        }

        semaphore.wait()

        return _peripheralType
    }
}
private var _peripheralType : peripheralType = peripheralType.unknown
```

In this case; the call is synchronous except for that first time. Maybe I need a completely different way of working with bluetooth devices? I'm looking for stable, easy to use patterns for connecting to peripherals and reading data from them.

Comment: Don't try and make asynchronous operations synchronous. Use `group.notify` if you want, but you may as well just write your code directly in the `connect` closure.  It isn't appropriate to use asynchronous methods in an initialiser.

Comment: How would you initialize a peripheral? Making a connection seems like a critical part of that initialization and I don't see how I can proceed to interact with the BLE device until I've established that connection. I could write a "connect" method that is meant to run after the constructor but I would run into the same deadlock issue there.

Comment: I could daisy-chain functions for my main connection and reading control sequence but that sort of logic is so hard to read and hard to maintain...I much prefer to have one function encapsulates a concise and clear overall control sequence.

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11, init shouldn't be async itself, better to have instance's API async.

Comment: ok, let me post another situation where this is causing a problem.

Comment: “Connected” is a state of a peripheral. Using frameworks like SwiftyBluetooth is OK, but you need to understand the underlying Core Bluetooth model. You can issue a `connect` for a peripheral that isn’t currently visible. When that peripheral is visible (possibly minutes, hours or even days later) the connect will complete.

Comment: In my case I am checking whether the peripheral is visible before I connect. The user initiates a connection by interacting with the physical peripheral; I connect and then need to read and write stuff to the peripheral. Maybe my use case is more synchronous than some? Maybe I'm just doing it all wrong?

Comment: The peripheral connection and type discovery is asynchronous. You can provide a closure that is called when this is complete or you could post a `Notification` but the former is probably more appropriate

Comment: Please take note of the second use case I posted. I'm looking for help waiting for asynchronous tasks in general; not necessarily in an initializer

Comment: You don’t “wait” for asynchronous tasks. You react to them. Think of it like a button tap. You don’t display a button and then “wait” for a tap. You show the button and then the action handler is called when the user taps on it. This is the same. Start the connection process and that object will let your observer know when everything is done.

Comment: Isn't this why most languages have the Async Await pattern including the next version of Swift?

Comment: There is a proposal for Async/Await but I can't find that it has been accepted into the Swift Evolution process; current opinion is they may be in Swift 6.  You can build the same solution right now with completion closures. Co-routines are syntactically nicer but don't offer anything that you can't already "build"

Comment: Wonderful; whoever gives me such an example will have the illustrious award of getting the accepted answer!

Comment: I will try and add an answer later, one clarification though is that it isn't appropriate to do this with the initialiser.